# Editing column names of a CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv, data-manipulation

I have a simple CSV file:

```
Alpha   Beta    Gamma
1       4       4
2       6       3
```

How can I add a specific integer or string to the column names, say 1 or "June"? The output I would expect is:

```
Alpha_1 Beta_1  Gamma_1
1       4       4
2       6       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paste` or `paste0` with `names`.

Assuming your `data.frame` is called `test`: `names(test) = paste0(names(test), "_1")`

Answer (score 1):

```
DF <- read.table(text='
       Alpha   Beta    Gamma
       1       4       4
       2       6       3', header=TRUE)


colnames(DF) <- paste(colnames(DF), 1, sep='_')
```